# Is there a better way to write android toolbar repeated methodes rather than writing the same code in every activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar

I have 3 activities, they all have a toolbar,they are all working fine,but all of them have a slight difference in their toolbar, so I had to write a lot of similar lines in every activity,is it possible to make a class for the toolbar custom xml layout the same as php ,in php when you make a header that is shared with all pages you program the header in a way that it dynamically changes depending on the page you are in,do note the code is working fine if they are separate my only problem is I want to keep my toolbar methods separate from my activity methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create you own toolbar that extends from android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.
like that

```
public class YourToolbar extends android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar{

public YourToolbar (Context context) {
    super(context);
    initViewComponents(context);
}


public YourToolbar (Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initViewComponents(context);
}

public YourToolbar (Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initViewComponents(context);
}
private void initViewComponents(Context context) {
   //here the shared code between all activities
     if(context instanceof FirstActivity){
    //code fore just the first Acitivity
     }if(context instanceof SecondActivity){
      //code fore just the secondAcitivity
     }else if(context instanceof ThreardActivity){
      }
    //here the shared code between all activities
  }
 }
```

in your xml views replace the default tolbar by yours

in the ativities classes replace the default toolbar by yours

Comment: i am facing 1 problem,in the initviewComp when i try to instantiate the toolbar it gives an an error  cannot resolve method on
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: could you please share with me this part of your code

Comment: it seems when you use action bar methods it become crazy i removed it and used inflate to bring up the popup menu and it worked fine.

Comment: setSupportActionBar(toolbar);  must called from an activity or you can pars you context to activity and call setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot of things regarding customization of toolbar, inheritance, includings, etc. One way is to inherit from `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`. Put your CustomToolbar to the appropriate activity_any_name.xml.

Each of the 3 Activities will inherit from your UpperActivity with the possibility to override especially custom settings that are only legal for own purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make a base activity in which you can define a method for toolbar decoration. All the similar line of codes for a toolbar can be written in that method. If you want that method should perform different decoration for every activity, you can take all the changes that has to be made in the form of method parameters. This will help you to reduce the repetitive line of code which you are writing in each and every activity.

Example:

```
class CustomBaseActivityClass extends AppCompatActivity{

// Overriden methods

// onCreate()

// onStart()

    public void decorateToolbar(Toolbar toobar //pass the toolbar reference to be attached,
    // optional: you can take required information from the extending activity to perform different actions for toolbar){

    // write the repetitive code for defining and attaching toolbar

    }

}
```

So, this will be the Base Activity class that will be extended from your rest of the activity rather than extending AppCompatActivity directly.

Now extend the CustomBaseAcitivity class for every new activity you create.
This can also be used for other repetitive codes which are occurring in your activities, by using inheritance you can reuse the codes written.
Rather than writing same codes again and again for every activity you can write it in a BaseActivity which will act as a Parent Class for every other activities.

```
SampleActivity extends CustomBaseActivity{

    void onCreate(// same overridden method){
        decorateToolbar(); // calling decorate toolbar method for attaching toolbar to the current activity.
    }
}
```